# Python colorbar ticks are labeled with an offset of +1 and not with specifed values

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to do a contourf plot of the divergence of a vector field with python and then add a colorbar to this plot. My levels are intended to be symmetric around zero from -0.01 to 0.01.

This is a part of my code:

```
div_levs = [-0.01, -0.005, -0.0025, 0.0025, 0.005, 0.01]
col = ['Blue', 'SteelBlue', 'White', 'Orange', 'Red']
c = plt.contourf(iwrf['x'], iwrf['y'], np.squeeze(iwrf['DIV'][ind_lev,:,:]), 
                 levels=div_levs, colors=col, extend='both')
c.cmap.set_over('Magenta') 
c.cmap.set_under('MidnightBlue')     
bar = plt.colorbar(ticks=div_levs)
bar.set_label('1/s')
```

If I execute the python script it works, and everything gets drawn in the right
way but the colormap is labeled with:

```
0.9900, 0.9950, 0.9975, 1.025, 1.0050, 1.0100
```

and on top of the colorbar a "-1" is displayed.

I've tried a lot, including setting the ticks of the colorbar after creating it,
or setting the ticks in debug mode but nothing seems to change this behaviour.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell the [colorbar](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar)'s [formatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=scalarformatter#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) to not use an offset by calling

```
bar.formatter.set_useOffset(False)
```

and then update the ticks with

```
bar.update_ticks()
```